# Can't Read Tables in Sqlite3 Database using Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I have many tables inside my sqlite3 database, one of them called GlobalData. I can read and write to it so I know it exists, however I can't check if it exists.

I have the following code in my app.js main file:

```
app.post("/update", function (req,res)
{
    var db = new sqlite3.Database("db.development.sqlite");
    db.get("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='GlobalData'", function (err, row)
    {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(row);
    });
});
```

However err is always null and row is always undefined.

I removed "AND name='GlobalData'" from the end of the query to try to get a list of all the tables, but the result is still the same (null and undefined).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible the filename is wrong? Meaning you're opening a fresh, empty, new database?

Comment: No, as the code after this section can edit and insert data into GlobalData

Comment: show me your collumn names..

Comment: Column names of GlobalData? They are three integer fields: goalsCompleted, peopleHelped and usersActive

Comment: When I test this with my own db and `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'` I get a single result, `{ name: 'sqlite_sequence' }`.

Changing `db.get` to `db.all` lists the above table, then the three I created myself.

Using `db.get` and SELECTing a specific name works for me, too, but the Capitalization of the table's name has to match exactly.

Comment: Thank you, I will try db.all in the morning and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: It works now funnily enough, maybe closing the server and restarting it fixed some strange error somewhere. Thank you!